# Calling invoke on Backbone Collection

Tags: backbone.js

I've a Backbone Collection initialized but calling **invoke** on collection doesn't work. For some reason I'm getting JS error:

```
var vw = new SomeView(); // A view with function 'refresh'  
var col = new Backbone.Collection();  
col.add(vw);  
...  
setTimeout(function(){ col.invoke('refresh'); }, 1000); // Error: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined
```

However, invoking method like **isEmpty** works fine

```
console.log("Is empty? ", col.isEmpty()); // prints: 'Is Empty? false'
```

It seems I'm missing something very obvious.

*N.B: I'm not interested in calling **each** function and then invoking **refresh** on view object because that's just clunky.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A collection in backbone is a list of models. So when you add a view to a collection internally it will call something like this `col.add(Backbone.Model.extend(vw))`. So it will create a new model with your view as constructor params. I f you wanna store your view in a list just use a JavaScript array or a smarter underscore collection

Comment: Beside other benefits of Backbone Collection (such as events being raised upon changes to collection), calling methods such as _invoke_ makes code more readable. My obvious alternate would be to use **each** method. Thanks for the help anyways.

Comment: If you need invoke use the underscore colleection.invoke method http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#invoke

Comment: Got it. You were right, views are turned into some model when added to collection and hence **invoke** won't find function **refresh** unless you **get** it (from internal model instance) and invoke it manually. I've switched to simple array as my data store and using underscore's **invoke** for method invocation. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

you try to create a collection by instantiating the collection itself,
you first have to extend from it and tell it what models it's holding
and of what i see above you are trying to put your views in a collection?
that is not possible directly, as a collection holds a list of models, not views.
you can however create a model defining your view.

```
var myView = Backbone.View.extend({});
var myModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var myCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({ model: myModel });

$(function(){

  // creating your view
  var vw = new SomeView();

  // creating a model for the view
  var viewModel = new myModel({ linkedview : vw });

  // creating a collection
  var modelList = new myCollection();
  modelList.add(viewModel);  

});
```

the gist of it is, that you create a model, containing a reference to your view, and not add the view directly into the collection (which will not work)

Comment: I guess than I'm better off using **each** rather making my code more murky and difficult to understand. BTW, I've used Collection with arbitrary JSON objects before and it works well for me.

Comment: yes, but you usually define a model that goes in the collection
all the json you then put in it, is put in a new instance of that model

Comment: I found @Andreas approach more simpler rather creating dummy model and then add to collection for very little use. Thanks for the help anyways.

Comment: it depends for what you want to use it later on, getting the view back from your collection seems difficult with @andreas' approach, since he extends the model from the view, all view properties are added on the model, so when you get it out you are actually working with a model object, not a view. Or i must be blind to how he add the view into the model.